# Tailwind presets get dynamic filename from .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, tailwind-css

I'm tying go get Tailwind to work with multiple configurations. As I read in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets), I could use presets for this.

Now I've created a second file called: "tailwind.clientname.js", and then called it within the tailwind.config.js file. Like so:

```
const project = process.env.PROJECT

module.exports = {
    presets: [require('./tailwind.' + project + '.js')],
}
```

I also created a `.env` file with the content:

`PROJECT="clientname"`

But when I run my yarn watch script, Tailwind doesn't seem to see the .env value
It returns as `tailwind.undefined.js`.

How can I make this work? Do I miss a dependency?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Thanks! That did the trick. If you answer my question, I'll mark you the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `process.env` (object containing the user environment) has no access to variables from `.env` file. To be able to load these variables from `.env` file you may install [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package

> Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`